# ListBox not displaying string (but bools) using databinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

i want to display a string and three bools in a listbox, therefor i made an ItemTemplate:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lstVars" Margin="10,41" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Height="30">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"/>
                    <CheckBox Margin="3" Content="a" IsChecked="{Binding save}" Width="200"/>
                    <CheckBox Margin="3" Content="b" IsChecked="{Binding displayBoard}"  Width="200"/>
                    <CheckBox Margin="3" Content="c" IsChecked="{Binding displayGraph}" Width="200"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

i made a testclass because with my original class it doesnt work (but the same "error" occurs with the testclass):

```
public class test
{
    public String description;
    public bool save { get; set; }
    public bool displayBoard { get; set; }
    public bool displayGraph { get; set; }

    public test(String description, bool save, bool displayBoard, bool displayGraph)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.save = save;
        this.displayBoard = displayBoard;
        this.displayGraph = displayGraph;
    }
}
```

when i add some values to the listbox, the string is not displayed

```
lstVars.Items.Add(new test("teststring", true, false, true));
```

[image: listbox]

i first thought the text would just be in a not visible row but when i write `Text="123test"` instead of `Text="{Binding description}"` it displays 123test like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare binding objects as properties. Like your bool properties.

```
public String description {get; set;}
```

Comment: big thanks to you! i never worked with databinding and i almost knew that i made just a stupid little mistake :-D

Comment: It's really little mistake, but causes a lot of headache :)